# How to efficiently query for a stacked column chart?

Tags: mysql, google-visualization

My use-case is creating a [stacked column graph](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts) using a logs table stored in MySQL.

Currently I have a regular column chart, but I would like to aggregate data by `site_id` so that I can see which parts of the bar are attributed to which site.

My current technique for the existing column chart is to get a list of dates, and count the records whilst grouping by the date. Then I use a for loop to create the 14 day period I need, and then loop my data to populate matching counts into the correct day.

```sql
SELECT DATE(`created`) AS `day`, 
       COUNT(`id`)     AS `count` 
FROM   `api_logs` `ApiLogs` 
WHERE  DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 day) AND CURDATE() 
GROUP  BY DATE(`created`) 
ORDER  BY DATE(`created`)
```

For the stacked chart though, I can't think of a way to collate the data in MySQL without performing a number of queries or building a subquery to collate the count per site.

Is there an established pattern for querying for a result which is easily compatible with the stacked column chart?

My front-end is built in PHP, if there are any post-query processing solutions.

Comment: Are you looking for a pivot table here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you need a column for each site

if you have a set number of sites, then you can build the columns manually in the sql

```
SELECT DATE(`created`) AS `day`,

       SUM(CASE WHEN `site_id` = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `site A`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `site_id` = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `site B`

FROM   `api_logs` `ApiLogs`
WHERE  DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 day) AND CURDATE()
GROUP  BY DATE(`created`)
ORDER  BY DATE(`created`)
```

otherwise, you can build the columns dynamically and aggregate
using google's [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) and [data.group](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group)

first, add `site_id` to the sql

```
SELECT DATE(`created`) AS `day`,
       `site_id`       AS `site_id`,
       COUNT(`id`)     AS `count`
FROM   `api_logs` `ApiLogs`
WHERE  DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 day) AND CURDATE()
GROUP  BY DATE(`created`), `site_id`
ORDER  BY DATE(`created`), `site_id`
```

which should result, similar to the following...

```
['Date', 'Site', 'Count'],
[new Date('11/17/2016'), 'A', 10],
[new Date('11/17/2016'), 'B', 15],
[new Date('11/17/2016'), 'C', 22],
```

see following working snippet for building columns dynamically...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // raw table data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Site', 'Count'],
      [new Date('11/17/2016'), 'A', 10],
      [new Date('11/17/2016'), 'B', 15],
      [new Date('11/17/2016'), 'C', 22],
      [new Date('11/17/2016'), 'D', 8],
      [new Date('11/16/2016'), 'A', 12],
      [new Date('11/16/2016'), 'B', 6],
      [new Date('11/16/2016'), 'C', 13],
      [new Date('11/16/2016'), 'E', 14],
      [new Date('11/15/2016'), 'A', 9],
      [new Date('11/15/2016'), 'B', 16],
      [new Date('11/15/2016'), 'D', 11]
    ]);

    // create view with columns for each site, then agg view
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    var aggColumns = [];
    var viewColumns = [0];

    data.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (site, index) {
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === site) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
          }
          return null;
        },
        label: site,
        type: 'number'
      });

      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index + 1,
        label: site,
        type: 'number'
      });
    });

    view.setColumns(viewColumns);
    var group = google.visualization.data.group(
      view,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(group, {
      isStacked: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```